# selected tab font color should be changed and also remain same on focus in zkoss

Tags: css, zk

In below code, the tab font (text) color changes, but on focus it doesn't. When I unhover the selected tab, it works fine. Can any one guide me on how I can change the text color on courser focus as well?

```
<style>
   .redtab .z-tab-seld  .z-tab-text{
      color:#e4710b;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 15px;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.redtab .z-tab-seld  .z-tab-text,.redtab .z-tab-seld  .z-tab-text:hover{
color:#e4710b;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: .redtab .z-tab-seld  .z-tab-text:focus

Comment: Welcome Manoj Singh,